# using maps with any value type as function parameter?

Tags: function, go, parameters, go-interface, go-map

I am trying to create a function which takes in a `map` as a parameter, where the map uses `string` keys but the values can be ANY type.

How do I make this work in go? I tried using `map[string]interface{}` as the parameter type to the function but that does not seem to work for example when passing in a `map[string]int` as an argument.

Any explanations as to what is the problem with this approach and if there is a way to achieve this in go?

Comment: Next year, if generics are added to Go 1.18, you should be able to do what you want (https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/VxeWRaAPE8k). But until then, you have to convert a `map[string]int` before passing it as `map[string]interface{}`. Alternatively your function could accept just `interface{}` and use `reflect` to do whatever it needs to do with the map.

Comment: Step 1. Start by understanding that `interface{}` doesn't mean "any type". (It means literally `interface{}`. Step 2: Decide if you want to A) redesign, B) fall back to (ugly) reflection or C) wait for parametric polymorphism (vulgo "generics" ) in Go 1.18. I'd recommend 1 + 2A.

Comment: @mkopriva that is exactly what I was hoping to do - well looks like I gotta wait and use the method you mentioned in the meanwhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function parameter is of type `map[string]interface{}` then you need to pass it a `map[string]interface{}` (and `map[string]int` is not  `map[string]interface{}`).

This is a common issue and is [covered in the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) (this focuses on slices but the same principal applies to maps).

The best approach really depends upon what you are trying to accomplish. You can do something like the following ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GRtQAMmnu1F)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    v := make(map[string]interface{})

    v["blah"] = 3
    test(v)

    v["panic"] = "string"
    test(v)

}

func test(in map[string]interface{}) {
    var ok bool
    converted := make(map[string]int)
    for k, v := range in {
        converted[k], ok = v.(int)
        if !ok {
            panic("Unexpected type in map")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(converted)
}
```

or accept an `interface{}` which allows anything to be passed in  ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mSX9qUxX-Lk)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    v := make(map[string]int)
    v["blah"] = 3
    test(v)

    w := make(map[string]string)
    w["next"] = "string"
    test(w)

    x := make(map[string]bool)
    x["panic"] = true
    test(x)

}

func test(in interface{}) {
    switch z := in.(type) {
    case map[string]int:
        fmt.Printf("dealing with map[string]int: %v\n", z)
    case map[string]string:
        fmt.Printf("dealing with map[string]string: %v\n", z)
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("unsupported type: %T", z))
    }
    // You could also use reflection here...
}
```